# Вывести содержимое переданного объекта в JSP странице

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

*Отправка объекта на jsp страницу:*

```
request.setAttribute("room", roomDB.getRoom(id));
```

*Моя реализация:*

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>number</th>
    <th>cost</th>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>${room.id}</td>
    <td>${room.number}</td>
<td>${room.cost}</td>
 </tr>
```

Как вывести содержимое переданного объекта?

Comment: Как у вас написано, так и нужно.